# UI automation and telerik controls

Tags: reflection, event-handling, automation, telerik, event-hooking

Most of the telerik controls are not supporting UI Automation.Is there any alternate method/approach to create a .Net tool for recording event details from telerik controls in the external wpf/window applications.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Telerik contols for WPF now support UI Automation through their own product - [Telerik Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/wpf-testing.aspx). You can download a trial and give it a try.